# Width of items in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, itemscontrol

I have an ItemsControl with a DataTemplate that is bound to an ObservableCollection of integers.

```
<ItemsControl Name="DimsContainer" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DimensionsTemplate}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

And in the Windows Resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DimensionsTemplate" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                       Padding="5"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="32"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

My problem is that in code, I need to be able to determine the width of the TextBlocks (or whatever the element is if I change it later) in the ItemsControl. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

When I do DimsContainer.Items[i] it gives me the bound item not the TextBlock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use instead:

```
DimsContainer.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
```

This won't give you the TextBlock itself, but it will give you the generated ContentPresenter that is wrapped around it by the ItemsControl to contain the ItemTemplate.

Comment: And how do I get the width from that?

Comment: Figured it out, thanks!
((FrameworkElement)(this.DimsContainer.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i))).ActualWidth;